# cannot find -lpthread

Tags: c, pthreads, compilation, cross-compiling, samba

I am trying to cross compile samba server.

./config works just fine, but when I want to build with make  the prompt says:

```
Linking shared library bin/libsmbclient.so.0
/opt/qnx630/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/ntoarm-ld: cannot find -lpthread
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/libsmbclient.so.0] Error 1
```

Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 2):

had this same problem w/mingw.  got libpthreadGC2.a from ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest/lib/x86/, put it in C;\mingw\lib and renamed it to libpthread.a.  i didn't know gcc's -l switch means "apprend 'lib' to the front and '.a' to the back" e.g. -lpthread = libpthread.a

Comment: this is linux!.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the `pthread` library is in the library search path of the linker.

Comment: Thans for your Answer, how can I look up, if the pthread library is in the library search path?